# AngularJS a.map is not a function during AJAX post calls

Tags: angularjs, json

I am getting this error whenever I call http.post in the console

```
angular.min.js:124 TypeError: a.map is not a function
at mh.n.writeValue (angular.min.js:310)
at Object.e.$render (angular.min.js:331)
at Object.$processModelValue (angular.min.js:301)
at Object.$$setModelValue (angular.min.js:301)
at angular.min.js:193
at m.$digest (angular.min.js:148)
at m.$apply (angular.min.js:151)
at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.min.js:288)
at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
at HTMLAnchorElement.q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3)
```

Here is the post code:

```
$http.post("/MyController/EditData", angular.toJson(myData), {
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }).then(function (response) {
        return response.data;           
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log("got an error in edit", e);
        throw e;
    });
```

Here is the data I am passing:

```
{
"customer":{"id": 1, "Name": "Joe", "Address": "Somewhere"},
"orderDates":[
        {"OrderDate": "Jul 01, 2018", "OrderTime": "07:40:00 AM", "DeliveryDate": "Jul 03, 2018", "DeliveryTime": "07:00:00 PM"},
        {"OrderDate": "Aug 01, 2018", "OrderTime": "07:40:00 AM", "DeliveryDate": "Aug 03, 2018", "DeliveryTime": "07:00:00 PM"}
        ]
}
```

The controller EditData accepts an object. I tried converting the object to an array before passing it but same error. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1. `myData` is not a valid JSON -> `"orderDates":{[ ... ]}` should be `"orderDates":[ ... ]`. 2. You don't need `angular.toJson()`

Comment: Edited orderDates

Comment: The error seems to come from the rendering of something, not from your AJAX request. Use the **non-minified** version of angular (and of everything else), to make it clearer where the problem comes from. The minified version is for production, not for development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);
app.controller("HttpGetController", function ($scope, $http) {

    $scope.keyword = '';

    $scope.GetAllData = function () {
        $http.get('/ServerRequest/GetData')
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.Details = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<br />status: " + status +
                "<br />headers: " + jsonFilter(header) +
                "<br />config: " + jsonFilter(config);
        });
    };

    $scope.SearchData = function () {

        var parameters = {
            keyword: $scope.keyword
        };
        var config = {
            params: parameters
        };

        $http.get('/ServerRequest/GetData', config)
        .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.Details = data;
        })
        .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
            $scope.ResponseDetails = "Data: " + data +
                "<hr />status: " + status +
                "<hr />headers: " + header +
                "<hr />config: " + config;
        });
    };

});
```